# How to add timer to RabbitMQ receiver?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Wasn't able to found any explanation on this.

As I understood about RabbitMQ, the simple example of message receiving
n C# Consumer looks like:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{    
   channel.QueueBind("Testing", "DefaultExcange", "Testing");
   var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);


   consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
   {
      var body = ea.Body;

      ...
      ...

      channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false, false);
   };

  channel.BasicConsume(queue: "Testing", autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

}
```

It will receive any message immediately, and if I remove BasicAck, messages will return to queue over and over again until It will be acknowledged.

What I want to do is to add a timer to this. If message wasn't acknowledged, I need to wait 30 seconds for the next acknowledge attempt for this message. Didn't found anything related to this issue, but I'm sure that this one is common one. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Delayed Message Exchange plugin:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/

Please note that this is a community plugin that does not ship by default with RabbitMQ.